# Cannot read property of undefined angular 2

Tags: angular

Here is my detail view component

```
import {Component,Input,Output,EventEmitter,OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';

import {TypeService} from './type.service'

import { PropertyTypes } from './type';

@Component({
    selector:'property-type-view',
    template:`
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <a [routerLink]="['../']" 
                    class="btn btn-success">
                   <i class="fa fa-list" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </a>
                <span class="title">

                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    {{(PropType | json).name}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    `,
    styles:[`
        .panel-default>.panel-heading>.title
        {
            color: #663663;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 250%;
        }
        .panel-default>.panel-heading>.btn
        {
            position: relative;
            top: -5px;
            margin-left:5px;
        }

    `]
})

export class TypeViewComponent implements OnInit{

    constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private service: TypeService) {}

    errorMessage: string;

    private PropType: PropertyTypes[];

    ngOnInit()
    { 
        // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
        let id = +this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
        this.service.getPropType(id).subscribe(
                        PropType => this.PropType = PropType,
                        error =>  this.errorMessage = <any>error  
                     );
    }
}
```

if i try to return the whole object `{{PropType.name}}` without pipe filter i get the same error below is my service  method

```
  getPropType(id:number):Observable <PropertyTypes[]>   {
    return this.http.get(this.TypeUrl+'/'+id)
                    .map(res=>res.json())
                    .catch(this.ThrowError);   }
```

Want i want to achieve is to be able to print properties type details using `{{PropType.name}}` without crashing the app with the error i have tried Async pipe with safe operator such as `{{(PropType | async)?.name}}` still no luck any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use: `*ngIf="PropType"` at the parent of `{{(PropType | json).name}}`? Because when html render your properties not.

Comment: I did try that before and still no luck

Comment: Hm..! Can you post your source? I will try to help

Comment: Thanks @cuongngo i managed to resolve the issue by immediately instantiating private PropType: PropertyTypes[]; to private PropType: any = ner PropertyTypes();